# error at calling webservices

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

i already done with my asmx which developed by using .net c# and it works well

but i found a error when i need to call the by using java android
error: java.lang.ClassCastException:org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive

result displayed at my asmx:

```
<customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<customerID>1</customerID>
<companyName>ABC</companyName>
<contactName>Jack</contactName>
<customerID>2</customerID>
<companyName>SS Company</companyName>
<contactName>Mary</contactName>
</customer>
```

my java cs:

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("custID", "member");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try
        {
         aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        tv.setText(resultString.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tv.setText(e.toString());          
        }                 
    }
```

the code above is functioning if i use http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

Comment: what is the value of `NAMESPACE`, `METHOD_NAME` and `SOAP_ACTION`? In which line do you get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it

```
           SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();           

            String addon = "";
            for(int i =0;i<resultString.getPropertyCount();i++)
            {                            
                SoapObject array2 = (SoapObject) resultString .getProperty(i);              
                addon = (addon + "ID = " + array2.getProperty(0).toString() + array2.getProperty(1).toString() + array2.getProperty(2).toString() + "\n");  
            }
            tv.setText(addon.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

1) change **userType** to **custID**. This a your fault.

Test [this](http://max-5.com.my/service.asmx/GetCustomer?userType=member).

In these situations ksoap2 serializer can not convert the returned string to a valid xml string.

2) Try this:

```
aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
tv.setText(resultString.getPropertyAsString("customerID"));
```

Comment: sorry, the actual is custID, not userType, i just did some changes... please ignore it :)
@breceivemail, i not sure, the error is at exception catch

Comment: ok, i can get the value now. but the result is like this. "anyType{customerID=Jack Sparrow; companyName=member;contactName=1234;} "how to filter this? i want the data only, i dun want those 'customerID', 'companyName', 'anyType' ...

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you have to parse a complex object. You must create an `Customer` class that implements `KvmSerializable` interface. Take a look at this: http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html